# How to get screenshot of VxWorks GUI?

Tags: gui

In Windows, everyone knows  will make screenshots to be copied into clipboard. It can then pasted into another programs. Now, I have a target platform which is running at VxWorks kernel v5.0.4. I would like to catch the screenshots into my Windows programs. How can I do it?

Comment: You got some good advice when you asked this identical qestion [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1173804/How-can-I-get-screenshots-of-GUI-of-vxworks-v). ***Did*** you contact WindRiver?

Comment: It's good idea, but now our contract of support was expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from ExpertExchange and they said no such function in VxWorks because it's an embedded system. An extra-camera is needed for such function.